# Why does preg_match doesn't find a string between tags when regex is OK?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have the next issue here. I'm trying to fetch a string between two HTML comment tags with preg_match/preg_match_all but the result I'm getting is empty array with a lot of records.

Here's my code:

```
$pattern = "/\<!-- Start of NewsTicker --\>(.*)\<!-- End of NewsTicker --\>/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $description , $matches);
```

The regular expression pattern itself seems to be valid since it works for me when I put just a short sample string (like: "123456") between two tags within $description variable.

However on the real life content it doesn't work and my guess is that this happens because of the content's length.

Here is the example of the real case the preg_match fails for me:
http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/6oJ

Could anyone explain please how the issue could be solved?
It's always possible to play with simple string functions like strpos, substr and etc. but isn't there other better options?

Thank you very much!

Comment: try this regex `(?s)<!-- Start of NewsTicker --\>(.*?)<!-- End of NewsTicker -->`

Comment: you need the `s` flag in your regexp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the "matches newline" flag, which is `s`.

So your regex should be the following:

```
$pattern = "/\<!-- Start of NewsTicker --\>(.*)\<!-- End of NewsTicker--\>/s";
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot it does work. To be honest I even didn't know that "." within a regex pattern doesn't include break lines.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried escaping your backslashes and other special characters? Also, it's typically better to use single quotes when dealing with pre-formatted text or RegEx.

like so:

```
$pattern = '/\\<\!-- Start of NewsTicker --\\>(.*)\\<\!-- End of NewsTicker --\\>/'
preg_match_all($pattern, $description , $matches);
```

Also helpful: [overapi.com/regex/](http://overapi.com/regex/)